# is it possible to switch the repo url when using pdm update python dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, pdm

I am using pdm v2.9.3 as the python dependencies manager, I was wondering is it possible to specify the download url when update some package? For example:

```
pdm update foo -url https://pypi.org/simple
```

most of time I am using the mirror address, but sometimes I need to download the newest package from official site. I just need to swith temporay, not change the download url forever.